# Python exclusive loop

Tags: python

I want to loop through a `list` and separate the current element from others.
Like this :

```
for e in the_list:
    function_call(e, <the_list but e>)
```

Is there an elegant way to do that ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is a duplicate as this requires the element to be known separately...

Comment: @JonClements: that's a good point.  We can always `zip` the list with the results of the answers to that question, though, but maybe some of us (myself included!) were a little quick on the trigger because it was clear that we could get both.

Comment: @DSM It is a little more complicated than that, as the order is actually reversed from what you want, hence my answer.

Comment: @Lattyware: the combination of `zip` and the `reversed` does make this sufficiently different to warrant not being closed, I think.

Comment: @DSM Five minutes later... XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `enumerate` and slice the list:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(the_list):
    function_call(elem, the_list[:index] + the_list[index + 1:])
```

Comment: When `index == 0`, wouldn't `the_list[:index]` be the same as `[elem]`?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen It'd be `[]`.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: `the_list[:0]` is empty. It's not the same as `the_list[:]`.

Answer (score 4):

A nice solution that reads (reasonably) well and doesn't need messing around with indices.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for item, rest in zip(data, 
                          reversed(list(combinations(data, len(data)-1)))):
...     print(item, rest)
... 
1 (2, 3, 4)
2 (1, 3, 4)
3 (1, 2, 4)
4 (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: +1 for ignoring an arbitrary number of elements.